# Deserialize mvc web api c# xml on client

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC web api that returns List
The XML returned to the client is like this:

```
<ArrayOfLeadChange xmlns="The-namespace">
<LeadChange>
...
<LeadChange>
<ArrayOfLeadChange>
```

I have copied the class LeadChange to the client and tries to Deserialize the xml to List, but i get an exception, that there is an error in the xml "Unexpected "

Is there a good way to Get or Deserialize, so that i can work with an object on the client side?

Comment: What kind of client? Javascript? .NET? Other?

Comment: The client is an ASP.NET C# application

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting` - that's part of Web API, but if you don't have Web API assemblies installed on the client you can get just the client bits from Nuget - http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/4.0.20710.0

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 4.0.20710.0
```

Then you can get from Web API and deserialize using `ReadAsAsync<T>` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944541(v=vs.108).aspx

For example:

```
var myobjects = Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<LeadChange>>().Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if deserializing manually is the correct path for your use case. But, if you want a good all-around XML deserializer try this.

EDIT: This is the correct function for returning a collection.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an XDoc into a List<T> of entities
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Any serializable object</typeparam>
    /// <param name="doc"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<T> DeserializeCollection<T>(XDocument doc)
    {
        if (doc == null)
            return null;

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
            XmlReader reader = doc.CreateReader();
            List<T> result = (List<T>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logging.Log(Severity.Error, "Unable to deserialize document.", e);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I am not sure why you have a namespace in the `<ArrayOf` node. Try removing it. That should work. You can also feed your List into this function to see what the "correct"/"expected" XML should be.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a List<T> of entities into an XDoc.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Any serializable object</typeparam>
    /// <param name="doc"></param>
    /// <param name="paramList"></param>
    public static XDocument SerializeCollection<T>(List<T> paramList)
    {
        if (paramList == null)
            return null;

        XDocument doc = new XDocument();

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(paramList.GetType());
            XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateWriter();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, paramList);
            writer.Close();
            return doc;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logging.Log(Severity.Error, "Unable to serialize list", e);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This resultet in the same error.
<ArrayOfLeadsChange xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Name.Space'> was not expected.

Comment: It results in the same exception. I will try to remove the root node.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear. You need the root node, just remove the namespace attribute.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out the code? Any problems I can help you with?